# How to frequently flush logs into output.xml file in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

While we run some robot script, the current logs of the script gets flushed into output.xml. But this happens only when execution of couple of keywords are complete.

Is there a way to frequently flush the current logs into the output.xml file? Maybe a timer that we can specify, and when that expires, the current logs should be flushed into output.xml, no matter if the code was in middle of running a keyword.

This would greatly help in identifying and debugging some issues quickly rather than waiting for the entire keyword or script to complete.

I am using Robot 3.1.2 (Python 3.5.0 on linux).

Comment: What have you looked at already? It seems that searching on GitHub for [RobotFramework Listener](https://github.com/search?q=RobotFramework+listener) shows quite a few results that could suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to frequently flush the current logs into the output.xml file?

No, there is not.

However, you can create your own output file with whatever data you want in it by creating a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface). A listener has access to all of the data that appears in the output.xml file, except for statistics.